# amplify configure Error fetching release: aborted

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am new to AWS. In the official documentation for using AWS Amplify in `Flutter`, it states to first install the `amplify cli` and then run `amplify configure`. When I run `amplify configure`, it takes a long time in showing `Downloading release from https://package.cli.amplify.aws/10.5.1/amplify-pkg-win-x64.tgz` and after that, it gives me `Error fetching release: aborted` error.
What is the solution for this? Thanks in advance.

***Note:** I have `node.js v18.12.1`, `npm 9.1.3` and `git version 2.34.1.windows.1` installed.*

Comment: For me, it was the slow internet connectivity problem!